# Dual objects in the $\infty$-category of spectra

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, higher-algebra

We say (according to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-category+with+duals) that a symmetric monoidal $(\infty,1)$ category $\mathcal{C}$ *has duals* if its homotopy category $h\mathcal{C}$ is rigid monoidal.

I'm interested in the $\infty$-category $Sp$ of spectra. What is the largest stable $\infty$-subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $Sp$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ has duals? Is such a category nontrivial? If so does it have a nice description? In this case the dual object of $X \in Sp$ is $Map(X, \mathbb{S})$, where $\mathbb{S}$ is the sphere spectrum $\Sigma^{\infty} S^0$.

Comment: The stable subcategory generated by suspension spectra of finite complexes.

Comment: @DylanWilson Is this the largest possible such category?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Well you can check that the homology with integer coefficients has to be finitely generated and projective (because smashing with HZ is monoidal to the derived category of chain complexes). Then use the homology of X as a guide to build a finite cell complex equivalent to X.

Comment: Any dualizable object $X$ satisfies $[X, Y] \cong [S, X^{\ast} \otimes Y]$ where $[-, -]$ is the mapping space and $S$ is the sphere spectrum; it follows that every dualizable object is compact in the sense that $[X, -]$ preserves filtered colimits. Now, I believe it's true that every spectrum is a filtered colimit of finite spectra (suspension spectra of finite complexes), so writing $X$ as such a filtered colimit, the identity map $X \to X$ necessarily factors through a finite spectrum, so $X$ is a retract of a finite spectrum. This is essentially the same as the proof that...

Comment: ...the dualizable objects in $k$-modules, $k$ a commutative ring, must be finitely presented projective. More generally, in a symmetric monoidal ($\infty$)-category, if the unit object is compact then every dualizable object is compact.

Comment: Right- that’s a better proof which works in much greater generality!

Comment: Actually maybe that only tells you every dualizable thing is a retract of a finite spectrum? Takes a tiny bit more to show those are closed under retracts (after all, the analogous statement for spaces is false)

Comment: I'd like to see the "tiny bit more".

Comment: You have to do that argument I gave above, I think, where you build a cell structure guided by the homology. The point is that a homology equivalence is an equivalence for desuspensions of connective spectra, but the same is not true for spaces unless they’re, say, simply connected

Comment: By the way, a keyword: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Spanier-Whitehead+duality

Comment: @DylanWilson Your and Qiaochu's comments together, perhaps after elaborating in response to Andre's comment, provide a complete answer. Do you mind leaving it as an actual answer?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan MO only allows one @..., but my previous comment was intended to be addressed to you and Dylan simultaneously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As requested, the comments turned into answers:

1. The dualizable objects in spectra are precisely the finite spectra (i.e. spectra of the form $\Sigma^{-k}\Sigma^{\infty}X$ where $X$ is a finite complex.)
2. If you only want the statement 'dualizable objects are finite spectra and their retracts' there is a very formal proof that works in great generality: (a) the unit in $\mathsf{Sp}$ is a compact and $\mathsf{Sp}$ is closed symmetric monoidal, (b) every object in $\mathsf{Sp}$ is a filtered colimit of finite spectra; it follows that every dualizable object $X$ is compact and that the identity map $X \to X$ factors through a finite spectrum, hence $X$ is a retract of a finite spectrum.
3. If you want to know that retracts of finite spectra are themselves finite, this is a bit less formal. One may argue directly or use (2) to show that, for $X$ dualizable, $H_*(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated and projective, hence free and concentrated in finitely many degrees. Now inductively build cell complexes $Y_j$ and maps $Y_j \to X$ which are equivalences on $H_m(-,\mathbb{Z})$ for $m\le j$. This stops at some finite step and you get a map $Y \to X$ from a finite complex to $X$ which is an equivalence on $H_*(-,\mathbb{Z})$. But $X$ is connective (lots of ways to see this... for example, by (2) it's a retract of something connective), so this map is an equivalence by Hurewicz. (Note: for spaces, this argument works as soon as $X$ is simply connected, but can fail because of Wall's finiteness obstruction when $X$ is not simply connected).

Obligatory: none of this had anything to do with $\infty$-categories.

Comment: Small nitpick: the general argument just tells you that all dualizable spectra are retracts of finite spectra, not the viceversa (of course it is easy to prove that finite spectra are dualizable by induction on the number of cells)

Comment: Perhaps this question is too general for the comments, but why do we define dualizability on the level of the homotopy category? I assume you said your answer has nothing to do with $\infty$-categories since we only care about the homotopy category. This just seems to contradict a general trend in higher category theory, where we require diagrams to commute up to coherent homotopy, not just homotopy. Does this make sense?

Comment: @leibnewtz: what is special about duals is that, like inverses, when they exist they exist uniquely up to a contractible space of choices. So there is no need to keep track of coherences.